# Javascript only passing first value from for loop

Tags: javascript, html, django, math

I am trying to sum the values in a for loop from my django database. Whenever I pass the loop through javascript, it only returns the first value in the array. I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to get all the values in the loop to pass through the script.

```
   {% for loans in d1_companies %}
        <div id="security-value">{{loans.market_value}}</div>

    {% endfor %}
    <div id="test"></div>                     



     <script>
     for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            let sum = document.querySelectorAll(`[id^="test"]`)[i];
            let values = [document.getElementById("security-value").innerText];


            const summed_value = values.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue);
            sum.innerText = summed_value;

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Call `.querySelectorAll()` **once**, save the list, and iterate through it. Calling it on each of 1000 iterations makes kittens in heaven cry.

Comment: Also "id" values have to be **unique** throughout a document. You cannot re-use them and expect anything to work.

Comment: You are reducing over the values array which has a single element.  I would expect all `document.querySelectorAll(\`[id^="test"]\`)` elements to contain the same value when this code is finished executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're looping through 1000 times. You can grab all instances of `security-value` (which I've changed into classes because as @Pointy mentioned, ids need to be unique), and loop through them.

```html
{% for loans in d1_companies %}
  <div class="security-value">{{loans.market_value}}</div>
{& endfor %}

<div id="test"></div>

<script>
  const security_values = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.security-value'));
  const security_values_inner = security_values.map((element) => element.innerText);
  const summed_values = security_values_inner.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue, 0);

  const sum = document.getElementById('test');
  sum.innerText = summed_values;
</script>
```

As an aside, be careful reducing over an element's `innerText` and blindly assume that it's a number. It could be, or it could be something else.

Comment: Hi thank you for this, I put the 1000 as a complete shot in the dark, not great with JS. Appreciate the help, I will try and implement it.

Comment: Hi, just ran it and it works! Thanks for help! Only part to adjust is accumulator + currentValue should both have parseInt() over them to add them instead of concatenating them together.

Comment: Nice! Yeah `parseInt()` should do the trick. Do you want to mark my answer as correct if it helped you out?